# what is the correct approach to push or segue a new view from only one cell of a dynamic tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistoryboard

IOS 6 , XCode 4.6.2  using storyboards

Heres my problem.  I have a tableview with 7 cells using dynamic prototype. I would like to segue from the third cell to another tableview (which is going to allow the user to select a country and pass that country back.)

Is it possible to set this up so only that one cell triggers the segue ?

If its not, then I presume I would need to use the didSelectRowAtIndexPAth method - but if i haven't drawn a seque in the storyboard i cant call performSegueWithIdentifier because there is no identifier- and no segue

Any ideas what should do ?

Cheers

Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't draw your segue from the cell prototype in the table.  Instead draw it from the `Files Owner` icon below your table view controller to the next table view controller.  Give it an identifier and then call

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueIdentifier" sender:self];
```

in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: ooh that looks like an interesting approach that i would never have thought about - I've gone with anils but may play with that idea later  - Thank you for the insight :)

Comment: In fact I'm going with your way and have now marked this as the correct answer.  This appears to be the better solution because in the new viewcontroller i define a delegate protocol thats used to the choosen country into my data store. This stopped working when using   DetailViewController *viewController=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];  but works as it should using your method  - brilliant

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a segue between view controllers you can use `push` methods of UINavigationController.

If you already have a segue between the two view controllers you can do this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   if(indexPath.row == yourCellIndex) {
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueIdentifier" sender:objectThatYouSendOrNill];
   }
}
```

If you are using static cells in your table view controller you can directly link segue from your cell to the destination view controller.

Comment: Cheers Danypata - I understand the format of the performseguewithIdentifier and have been using that elsewhere with no problems in apple template for didselectRowAtIndexPath they have some dummy code as follows     
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     */        but as i'm using storyboard i don't have a nibname for the view controller as its on my storyboard and not a seperate file. Ideas ?

Comment: So then, what's the problem (maybe I didn't understand your question)? You can't create a UIStoryBoardSegue programmatically, if you don't have a segue then you have to push/presentModal your view controller ;)

Comment: If i create a segue from the dynamic prototype, all the cells jump to the new view and i only want the one to do that. Do i need to take the   new viewcontroller off the storyboard and stick it into a seperate nib - which seems silly - or do i need to scrap the dynamic approch and go for static cells?

Comment: Dynamic approach is when you have dynamic cells (unknown number, properties etc.). If your cells are always the same then, yes use static cells into your tableViewController and then you can link segues from each of them. But why bother ? Use `didSelectRow` because in this case the code is `more` reusable ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can design the DetailViewController in storyboard itself. Give a StoryboardID for that view controller. and in  didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if(indexPath.row == 3)
  {
    DetailViewController *viewController=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
   }
}
```

Dont forget to give `StoryboardId` for the DetailViewController  as `DetailViewController`

Comment: Cheers Anil that looking more like what i need - a storyboard substitute for initialising with a nib - one last thing though, my table view is within a view on a tab bar controller so the substitute for self.navigationcontroller would be...

Comment: You have two options.. !. 1. [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil]; Then you wont get that feel(pushing). One better approach add a navigation controller to the storyboard link tab bar->nav controller -> yourviewController(table view) then push detailView by code